# Difference between measures and relationship to standard pdfs

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

this might seem a stupid question but I'm struggling to answer it myself.

From beginner's probability we know that the standard normal distribution has density $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}$$

However, I am reading Le Gall's Brownian Motion, Martingales and Stochastic Calculus where he defines the former as a density with respect to the Lebesgue measure.

So this got me thinking, is it trivially obvious that

$$\int_{-\infty}^t\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}dx=\int_{(-\infty,t)}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}d\mu$$

where $\mu$ is the Lebesgue measure?

Obviously, the chosen density has no specific properties(except possibly that it integrates to $1$) but this is not the point of the question.

I know (though the proof was not given to me) that $\mu((a,b))=b-a$ but still, can't we have a cover of $(-\infty, t)$ in my specific case on top which consists of more complicated elements?

Hopefully the question makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

This [Criterion for an Improper Riemann Integrable Function to be Lebesgue Integrable](http://mathonline.wikidot.com/criterion-for-an-improper-riemann-integrable-function-to-be) should help. One needs to check that the Riemann integral of the absolute value of the improper integrable function is bounded by the same positive constant over all finite intervals.